# How are linux filesystems created?

Tags: linux, filesystems

i've been studying the linux operating system for a while now, i understand what file systems are but i'm curious as to how they're made. Is it possible for a programmer to create their own custom made file system in linux, is it possible to combine multiple file systems together and how much control do we have over a file system? Thanks.
Also does anyone know any online sources or books that talk about linux file systems

Comment: I'm afraid your question is way to broad to be answered here. There surely are a lot of technical descriptions of file systems available. One starting point would be to read the [article about FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Certainly a programmer can create a file system, everyone can, you just have to use the command to do that. In addition to that a programmer *theoretically* can implement logic that creates what you probably refer to as "custom made filesystem", just as a programmer can change, remove or add anything he wants from any part of the system he uses. It is questionable though if many programmers actually are able to create a *working* and *usable* file system from scratch, since that is quite a complex thing to do.

Combining multiple filesystems is certainly possible, but maybe you should define in more detail what you actually ask by that. You certainly can use multiple filesystems inside a single system by simply mounting them. You can mount one filesystem inside another. You can even use a loopback device to store a whole filesystem inside a file contained in another filesystem. What you can *not* do is somehow take two separate file systems, hold a magic wand over them and declare them as one from now on. Well, actually you can do that but it won't work as expected ;-)

About the last question, how much control we have... well, difficult to answer without you giving any metric to do so... We certainly can *configure* a filesystem, we can *use* it and its content. We can even destroy or damage it, mount it, check it, examine it, monitor it, repair it, create it, ... I personally would indeed call that some amount of "control" we have over filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know any online sources or books that talk about linux file systems